# Is there an R function/loop that can add a unique number or string to a filename?

Tags: r

I am new to R and Stack Overflow. I have looked extensively for an answer to my question, and I don't believe this is a repeat question.

I have .csv files that are loaded into my script as data frames, and I need those data frames saved as .Rda or .RDS files.

The way I have the code written, the old .Rda files will get overwritten in the directory I have them saving to.

```
base::save(data, file="data.Rda")
```

Is there a way to create a loop that attaches some random number or string onto a pre-existing file name when it is save, or even a function that generates a unique ID #? What I am looking for is an output that looks like

data_1.Rda
data_2.Rda
data_3.Rda
and so on where the _# is randomly generated every time I run the code.

I have tried to create a vector such as

```
x<-c(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k)
```

then created a loop to save through each individual variable, but the loop simply saved the data frames as "a", "b", "c"...I want to know if there is a way to attach those individual variables to a pre-existing name ("data_a.Rda", "data_b.Rda"...)

I am not particular about any method just as long as it works.

Comment: You can check with `file.exists` and if so, then create an unique file name

Comment: @akrun the post you have linked is similar but I do not believe it answers this particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose I have a directory like this:

```r
/Documents (R home)
     |
     |-- my_data
             |
             |--data_1.Rda
             |--data_2.Rda
```

Then I can list the files in the `my_data` directory with:

```r
list.files(path.expand("~/my_data/"))
#> [1] "data_1.Rda"  "data_2.Rda"
```

And I can generate the "next" Rda file path with a simple function:

```r
next_rda <- function() {
  f <- list.files(path.expand("~/my_data/"), pattern = "^data_\\d+\\.Rda")
  num <- max(as.numeric(gsub("^data_(\\d)\\.Rda", "\\1", f)) + 1)
  paste0(path.expand("~/my_data/data_"), num, ".Rda")
}
```

So that I can do:

```
next_rda()
#> [1] "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/my_data/data_3.Rda"
```

This means if I want to save an object I can do:

```r
save(obj, file = next_rda())
```

Which will save to the next incremental file. Since the function checks the directory each time, it always writes to a new file, numbered appropriately.

Comment: Hi Allan, I believe this is the function that I have been looking for; however, when I go to use the save function, I get an error that says, "Unused arguments: next_rda()". Do you have any suggestions as to why that is? The next_rda() function itself works.

Comment: @LG_research sorry, that should be `file = next_rda()`

Answer (score 0):

I would check the existence of the filename.
If it's exists, then create some sort mechanism to create a new filename.
Whether it be a randomly generated string or a numbering system.

FYI:
You could store multiple variables in 1 rda file by:

`> save(data1, data2, data3, file = "data.rda")`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `?tempfile`. It can generate unique filenames for you to use.